# Links clicked in emails not finding their proper template and controller with ngRoute

Tags: angularjs, mean, ngroute

If I set a link in an email to link back to say an /password/edit route, it resolves to the '/' route.

`http://localhost:1337/#/password/edit?token=ZL6VusxDU`

resolves to

`http://localhost:1337/#/?token=ZL6VusxDU`

and if I click back in the browser then it resolves properly to this route:

```
$routeProvider.when('/password/edit', {
  templateUrl: 'templates/password-edit',
  controller: 'PasswordEditCtrl'
});
```

I'm using ngRoute and have tried with and without `base(href='/')` and `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`. Any help much appreciated.